# Oracle: updating data in referenced partition scenario is taking longer time

Tags: oracle, partitioning

I have table partitioned on a column(rcrd_expry_ts) of date type. We are updating this rcrd_expry_ts weekly by another job. We noticed the update query is taking quite longer time (1 to 1.5 min) even for few rows and I think longer time is taken for actually moving data internally to different partitioned. There can be a million of rows eligible to update rcrd_expry_ts by our weekly job.

```
 CREATE TABLE tbl_parent 
(   
   "parentId" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "RCRD_DLT_TSTP" timestamp default timestamp '9999-01-01 00:00:00' NOT NULL
)
PARTITION BY RANGE ("RCRD_DLT_TSTP") INTERVAL (NUMTOYMINTERVAL('1','MONTH'))  (PARTITION "P1"  VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('2010-01-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')));

 CREATE TABLE tbl_child 
 (
   "foreign_id" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,
   "id" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
   constraint fk_id foreign key("foreign_id") references 
   tbl_parent("parentId")
 )partition by reference (fk_id);
```

I am updating RCRD_DLT_TSTP in parent table from some another job (using simple update query) but I noticed that it took around 1 to 1.5 min to execute, probably due to creating partition and move data into corresponding partition. Is there any better way to achieve this in Oracle

Comment: As a general rule, you should be partitioning on a record value that is "static", that rarely or never changes once the record is created. As you have discovered, an update can become quite slow if the record has to be moved with a value change. Partitions are wonderful for aging out old data and bulk loads. You might want to think about using an index instead of the partition.

Comment: Perhaps the table is logically small (number of rows) but physically large (number of bytes used by the segments). This can happen if there's a large number of mostly empty partitions and the segment overhead is consuming a huge amount of space. Run this query to see how many partitions and bytes are in these tables: `select count(*) number_of_partitions, sum(bytes)/1024/1024/1024 gb from dba_segments where segment_name in ('TBL_PARENT', 'TBL_CHILD');`  If the number is much larger than expected you may need a different partitioning strategy, deferred segment creation, or something else.

Answer (score 0):

The table has a referenced partitioned child. So any rows moving partition in the parent will have to be cascaded to the child table too.

This means you could be moving substantially more rows that the "few rows" that change in the parent.

It's also worth checking if the update can identify the rows it needs to change faster too.

You can do this by getting the plan for the update statement like this:

```
update /*+ gather_plan_statistics */ <your update statement>;
  
select * 
from   table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor( format => 'ALLSTATS LAST' ));
```

This will give you the plan for the `update` with its run time stats. This will help in identifying if there are any indexes you can create to improve performance.

> Is there any better way to achieve this in Oracle

This is a question that needs to be answered in the larger context. You may well be able to make this process faster by unpartitioning the table and using indexes to identify the rows to change.

But this affects all the other statements that access this table. To what extent do they benefit from partitioning? If the answer is substantially, is it worth making this process faster at the expense of these others? What trade-offs are you willing to make here?